# debug and release versions of index.html

Tags: html, debugging, release

I need to créate a version of index.html for debug and another one for reléase, mainly to add versioning to js in release src so that it does not get cached. Is there a way to do this similar to the web.debug.config and web.release.config? If so, how is it done? Just add the files with the ".debug." and ".release."?

Comment: which framework(s) are you using?

Comment: .NET framework 4.5.2

Comment: And which Web frameworks? Webpack, gulp, bower, npm? Things like this is crucial to know in order to give you a relevant answer. Or you could just try a google search for it - you'll probably find an answer.

Comment: Sorry, missed your point. I'm using bower & npm. The UI Project is an angularjs 1.5.x Project.

Comment: Bower and NPM are "just" package managers. Of course you can use them to accomplish what you want - but it would probably be cumbersome. Take a look at webpack - it has plugins to do what you want.